# Given an arbitrary object check that the object has a given key and if it does return the value for that key in typescript

Tags: javascript, json, object, typescript

Given an arbitrary object I would like to check that it is of this form.

`obj = {WHERE:{antherObject},OPTIONS{anotherObject}}`

I can check if the object has the key using `hasProperty(key)`
 but after that how do I access the value of the key?

I was thinking something like this.

```
validateForm(obj: Object):Object { 

if obj.hasOwnProperty("WHERE") {
//return the value of "WHERE"
}
else{
throw new Error("WHERE isnt a key in this object");}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript (and typescript) there are two ways to access object properties:

1. Dot notation, eg `obj.WHERE`
2. Bracket notation, eg `obj['WHERE']`

You'll generally use dot notation when you know what key you're looking for. You have to use bracket notation when you are using a variable or dynamically generated value as the key.